# How to find feature including a specific element

Tags: visual-studio, feature

this migth be a really easy question, but I could not find any solution for that.

I'm using VS 2012 and want to find which features are using a specific element.
Since I got lots of Features in my Solution and loading them in designer takes ages, I'm looking for a way to see, which feature uses my element (SiteColumn, ContentType, whatever).

The root cause of the problem is, that VS throws new elements to a more or less random feature.

Answer (score 0):

I would use Packaging explorer, that opens by default when you open up the Package.package file. You see a list of all your features and the Elements and Modules in them!

Note that this is per project view, not per solution.

Comment: That's better than nothing, but with a lot of features still is difficult to see if there are duplicates ..

Comment: Truly! I just hate Visual Studios "feature" to automatically add elements and modules to the first matching Feature...